# callout accessory not appearing

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mkpinannotationview

I am trying to add a generic callout accessory to my annotation area but its not showing up for some reason.
Here's the code:

```
- (void) setupMap:(PFObject*) venue {

...

OTNVenueAnnotation *annotation = [[OTNVenueAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude);
annotation.title = [[venue objectForKey:@"name"] uppercaseString];
annotation.venue = venue;


UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
customPinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
[self.mapView addAnnotation: annotation];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the leftCalloutAccessoryView in the delegate method of the map view *viewForAnnotation*, for example:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation 
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView= (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    annView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    return annView;
}
```